# White spaces not ignored in pre tag

Tags: html, whitespace, pre

I have read that the 'pre' tag will collapse all white spaces and tabs into one space, but it doesn't do so for me.

why is it so? is it depending on web browser or should I do something more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4)

> The PRE element tells visual user agents that the enclosed text is "preformatted". When handling preformatted text, visual user agents:
>
> - May leave white space intact.
> - May render text with a fixed-pitch font.
> - May disable automatic word wrap.
> - Must not disable bidirectional processing

PRE tags will leave white space as you have typed it.  The purpose is just that.  If you don't use a pre tag, standard HTML will collapse white space as you have written.  Use PRE if you are interested in *preserving* white space, not *collapsing* it.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CwLQw/2/) in JSFiddle.

This will **preserve** white space:

```
 <pre>
    Spaces
     and more
      galore
 </pre>
```

This will **collapse** white space:

```
 <div>
   All
    together
     now
 </div>
```

Comment: so it reserve all white spaces.

Comment: Yes.  It's the entire point of the PRE tag.  For instance, it's used for "code" (e.g. if you are typing C++) or poems / any work where you have done the work of spacing already.  HTML generally doesn't preserve this space so that you can better structure your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

The PRE tag will just keep you contents in the same format as you wrote it.
it is used to keep your "preformatted" text the same way as you wrote it.